# Navigate to browser window tab by given number

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a command that will navigate to browser's tabs by number.

```
public void NavigateToBrowsersTabByNumber(int nr)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + nr);
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[nr -1]);
}
```

The main problem is that it works only if active tab is the first one (windows handle index 0). Otherwise it will stay at the current tab. If I manually navigate to the first tab and switch to first handle `driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);` everything again works as expected when call the method.

**Summary:** 
The `SendKeys` works only if the first tab is focused.

I'm using selenium webdriver: v2.48.1.

Answer (score 0):

why not directly use tabs.get function, instead of sending keystrokes?

`public void NavigateToBrowsersTabByNumber(int n)
    {
        ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList (driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(n-1));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The first opened tab should automatically have focus. But if it doesn't from some reason than you can add focus manually to it and then use SendKeys. Try this :

```
    driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
    IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
    body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Tab);
```

This should switch to next tab or if you want to switch to specific tab e.a.

```
    body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + +Keys.NumberPad2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this in python.  I just call the method and pass it which tab I want to access

```
def switch_to_new_window(driver, window):
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[window])
```